# Rebus puzzle: .25.25 .25.25

Tags: rebus

I've recently come across a Rebus puzzle from a friend that I cannot figure out. Anyone who can help, I would really appreciate it!! This is what it looks like below

> .25.25
>   .25.25

That is it. Please help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 52):

In all likelihood, those are

> Close quarters

Answer (score 12):

Maybe it is a

> pound cake

or as we call it in France a

> quatre quarts

which is basically

> 4 times 0.25, and a cake that requires 4 ingredients in even proportions

Comment: Really nice one +1

Answer (score 6):

How about:

> [forequarters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forequarters) as in the front two legs of a quadruped (as opposed to the hindquarters)?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> four quarters in a square.

<sub>I got it after checking the markdown of your question and seeing that the two `.25.25`s were meant to be on separate lines. (To force a line break even without a whole paragraph gap, put two spaces at the end of the previous line.)</sub>

Comment: What is "four quarters in a square"? I checked on google-sensei, nothing came up '-'

Answer (score 2):

It can be easy math problem.

> .25.25 -> quarter of quarter and then using addition

.25.25

.25.25

---

.50.50.50

OR

One Year:

> Four seasons (Vivaldi? :)

OR

Poetry:

> T.S. Eliot: Four Quartets

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE :) I get that you're saying about the total probability theorem but a [Rebus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus) is generally a phrase or set of words coming out of a picture. Can you rephrase your answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Foursquare

Because

> It's a square of fourths

Comment: The spoiler thing is still not working for me

Comment: Nevermind I got it

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> a four square (http://www.squarefour.org/home), a game?!

As

> all 0.25 are squares of 0.5

Comment: @Flater, four 0.25s are provided, literally. Is it not?

Comment: I don't really understand the justification "all 0.25 are squares of 0.5." Why is 0.5 relevant? Any nonnegative real number is the square of some other number. If the numbers were instead all 0.2209, would you say that they were all squares of 0.47? For 0.1138 would you say that they are all the squares of sqrt(0.1138)? These are all true, but they seem pulled out of thin air.

Comment: Every positive number is the square of something.

Comment: This doesn't add up.

Comment: @wchargin It's the same way we say that 4 is a square, but 2 isn't. Sure, in the reals, 2 is a square, but in the reals, "is a square" is a useless property because it applies to all non-negative real numbers. In the rationals, it's a meaningful property. Yes, I would say 0.2209 is a square, and no, I would not say 0.1138 is a square.